# Index entry with nameref content leads to emergency stop

Tags: indexing, expansion, nameref

Good evening, everybody.
After having read lots of your formidable Q&A's (thank you for the insights) I am struggling hard with this problem and would like to pose a question:

What I intend to do is derive from the content of a *part* (which functions as a book title in a collection of handbooks) only a special substring (which can be derived by cropping after a " - " and (apart from outputting it) make an entry to the index.

This works "by hand" using the following MWE (problematic part commented out):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,parskip=full]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex

\newtoks\VATemp{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\getnamereftext}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{r@#1}{}{%
    \unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@thirdoffive\csname r@#1\endcsname
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\VA}[1]{
    \StrBehind{\getnamereftext{VA #1-Start}}{ - }[\VATemp]
    \index{VA #1 - \VATemp}%
}

\begin{document}
\part{Verfahrensanweisung 145-1.8 - Just a Test}% ä to test for Umlaut
\label{VA 145-1.8-Start}

\VA{145-1.8}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

EDIT:
When I use an "ä" in the title of a part, I don't get any index entry (or so it seems). To be exact, main.idx contains the following:

> \indexentry{VA 145-1.8 - Just \unhbox \voidb@x \bgroup \U@D 1ex{\setbox \z@ \hbox {\char 127}\dimen@ -.45ex\advance \dimen@ \ht \z@ \fontdimen 5\font \dimen@ }\accent 127\fontdimen 5\font \U@D a\egroup Test|hyperpage}{1}

which means, that the Umlaut is expanded very strangely (and leads to an error concerning UTF-8 in Overleaf).

Does anybody know a way around this? Will I have to look at the extraction of thepartname by nameref or rather at the indexing process...? Or did I miss any Options in inputenc / imakeidx or any other package?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved by using `\noexpandarg` so the string is not subject to full expansion, which would remove the `\unexpanded` protecting it.

However, one further expansion step is needed in order to remove `\@thirdoffive`.

Instead of the standard `\expandarg` used by `xstring`, a single `\edef` that will remove `\unexpanded`, but not doing further expansion, is used.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,parskip=full]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\getnamereftext}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{r@#1}{}{%
    \unexpanded\expandafter
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      {%
       \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@thirdoffive\csname r@#1\endcsname
      }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\VA}[1]{%
  \begingroup\noexpandarg
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\StrBehind
    {\getnamereftext{VA #1-Start}}}%
  \x{ - }[\VATemp]%
  \index{VA #1 - \VATemp}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\part{Verfährensanweisung 145-1.8 - Just a Test}% ä to test for Umlaut
\label{VA 145-1.8-Start}

\VA{145-1.8}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
I will edit my first post so the space will be saved (sorry for that)!

You saved me a lot of headache!